# What is use of a makefile?

Tags: qt4, qmake

What is the purpose of a makefile, .pro file?

Comment: You should google these before asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makefiles simplify executing the necessary commands for building a program, I'll point you to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile for details on makefiles (something you can easily look up yourself).

The `*.pro`-file is a Qt-specific artifact for qmake projects, which you could also easily look up on Google: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.1/qmake-project-files.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a platform independent file used to create platform specific make files when the project is actually compiled.

You might want to read this: [Qmake manual - 4.5](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmake-manual.html)